# How to skip the support for iPad , iPad 2, and iPad 3 when submitting iOS games and apps to Apple App store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am developing and testing my iOS game on my REAL device that is the iPad 4 (fourth generation), and it works well on the REAL iPad 4.  However, I have not tested the game on the REAL older iPads such as iPad 1 and iPad 2 or even iPod. So, I would like to have 3 questions that are related to one another as follow:

**(1) Xcode Simulator ?**
The real iPad 1 only has 256 Mb of RAM, and the real iPad 2 only has 512 Mb of RAM. In addition, the processors of these 2 devices are certainly slower that those of the new iPads.  (Unfortunately, I don't have the money to buy iPad 1 and iPad 2 for testing.)

So, if I use the Xcode simulator to test my game on these 2 devices, will the simulator accurately set up the test conditions that truly reflect the limitations of the RAM, processor speed and hardware performance of these 2 devices ? Please show me how to do that if there is a way to do that ?

(Honestly, I think that the XCODE simulator is just that: it is a simulator and NOT an emulator. Therefore, I doubt that the XCODE simulator can accurately simulate the testing conditions on the real iPad 1 and iPad 2 devices, and hence, I am afraid that my test on XCODE simulators won't be accurate. For example, the simulator may show that the game works fine, but in reality, when users install that game on the real iPad 1 and 2, it may have some lagging issue with the animation to say the least...)

**(2) Skipping the iPad 1, iPad 2, iPad3, and iPod ?**
Is there a way for me to tell Apple that I only want to release my game to iPad 4 (fourth generation) and newer generations of iPad, and I don't want to release my game for the iPad 1 and iPad 2 ?

**(3) Apple Regulation ?**
Or does Apple enforce the rule that says that all iPad games must work for all generations of iPad (including iPad 1 and iPad 2) before developers can release the games for sale on the App store ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no such rules. There are two things which decide what devices should be supported.

**1) Deployment target**

So if your deployment target (Oldest iOS version supported) is iOS8 or iOS9 it means you need to support iPad 2 but not iPad 1 as iPad 1 cant run on iOS 8 or 9. You can wait for Xcode 8 public version and you can set minimum iOS to iOS10 , that will eliminate iPad 2.

If you want to skip both iPad 1 and iPad2 I would not run on that.

**2) Valid Architecture**

You can only support 64 bit processor (arm64) in build settings that will discontinue app for those devices which are not running on 64 bit processor. By doing this your app will only run on devices with Apple A7 and more Processors (You can figure out the devices)

Based on these two settings you can decide which devices you should be supporting

Comment: Thank you very much. This is an excellent answer as it helps me to skip the support for iPod, iPad 1 and probably iPad 2 in the future. BTW, if possible, would you please show me the Apple webpage that specifies which version of iPad and iPhone can be upgraded to iOS 9 and iOS 10 ? (I may need that for future reference.)  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: You can find list of devices upgradable to iOS 10 right at the bottom of this page http://www.apple.com/in/ios/ios10-preview/  and you can find list of devices that can be upgraded to iOS9 at the bottom of this page http://www.apple.com/in/ios/whats-new/

Comment: Wow. That is awesome. Thank you so much for your excellent help.

Answer (score 2):

You can make an app iPad only. That removes the iPod from the equation.

Apple doesn't let you arbitrarily block certain versions of a device, but You **can** restrict your app based on OS version. The iPad 1 is old and only works up to iOS 7, if memory serves. You are likely using APIs that won't run on the iPad 1 already.

There are certain hardware-based APIs that are only available on some devices, and if your app requires one of those then it will exclude some devices.

Older devices are both slower and have less RAM. You should really test on the lowest spec device you support. (The sim is no good for performance or low memory testing.) eBay is a good source of cheap older devices.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is an good way to skip support for iPad 1 and iPod. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the requirements you can state a specific version of iOS or higher. I don't know accurately which versions of iOS that iPad 2 can support up to (for sure that iPad 1 will support up to a lower version than that one supported by iPad 2). Stating this so you excluded iPad 1 and 2. Moreover, you can state that this app is for iPad only, so you also excluded iPod and iPhone as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. With your suggestion, I can ignore the support for IPad 1 and iPod. I have not even thought about support for iPhone yet.

Comment: The iPad 2 runs iOS 9.x. (Not very well, but it does run iOS 9. Under iOS 9.x It's slow and tends to run out of memory.) The iPad 2 will not support iOS 10.

Comment: Once iOS 10 is released so you can easily exclude iPad 2. However, iPad 3 devices which aren't upgraded to iOS 10 will be temporarily excluded until they are upgraded to iOS 10.

Comment: @Duncan C :  Thanks to both of you (Mina and Duncan C). I am looking forward to uploading iOS 10 onto my iPad for testing whenever it is available. I am so glad that we won't have to make our game work for iPad 2.  :-)